# Azure Data Factory Pipeline Calling a Stored Proc on Another Server

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I have a stored Proc in Server A (Cloud VM) that I want to define in ADF and scheduled to be executed there.

Im going thru examples in the web and it seems that it always to refer to as the stored proc residing in a AzureDB or AzureDW.

Any resource or example that would help me acheive what I want?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the linked service type OnPremisesSQLServer and data set type SQLServerTable instead of AzureSQLDatabase and AzureSQLTable